# definition of an event

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Perhaps I am being very meticilious with my definitions here but I am reading Sheldon Ross's "A first course in Probability" and it describes an event as "Any subset of a sample space". 
So if we define a sample space of dice outcomes as {1,2,3,4,5,6} then {3,4} 
would be a legitimate subset (going back to the "event is any subset" definition),however {3,4} would not be an "event" of a single dice throw if it makes any sense.Is there something I am missing out on?

So I am confused a bit here.

Comment: {$3,4$} means the event that either $3$ or $4$ is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

$\{3,4\}$ is an event of a single dice throw. For any single throw of a die, you can ask "did the event occur?" (In this case, "did I throw a $3$ or $4$?")

Perhaps you are thinking of outcomes, which can only be single elements of the sample space. E.g., $3$ is a legitimate outcome for a die roll. $3$ also happens to be in the event $\{3,4\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The elements in the sample space are the possible *outcomes*, and the sample space is the set of all possible outcomes (*or even some impossible ones too*).  An *event* is a collection of outcomes.

Imagine if you will that you were playing a boardgame like Sorry.  You want to jump on an opponent's piece, but you don't care which.  You can do this either by rolling a $3$ or by rolling a $4$, but not by rolling anything else.  You ask the question "What is the probability that I can jump on an opponent?"

The event here, "I jump on an opponent" happens to be the event $\{3,4\}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can see it as the event that the value of the dice is in the subset $\{3,4\}$. So the value of the die is 3 or 4.